# How do I add reCaptcha to a form programmatically?

Tags: 8, forms

I have a custom form on my site, and I want to attach a reCaptcha to it. I wasn't successful using the Drupal 7 code for this. Suggestions?
This is the Drupal 7 code I'm using:

```
$form['recaptcha'] = array(
  '#type' => 'recaptcha'
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following (after installing the [reCaptcha module](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha)):

```
$form['captcha'] = array(
  '#type' => 'captcha',
  '#captcha_type' => 'recaptcha/reCAPTCHA',
);
```

Comment: And how to show the inline error for captcha. For ex: Just below the captcha field?